# Inserting batch data in mysql with queries on textarea in java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, insert

I want to make a program that is connected to mysql database, in my program the queries are dynamic, the user will input his query on a textarea and then after pressing the button the program will execute the query and returns/displays the time consumed for the execution. I have no problem on select query but I have problem inserting batch data. here's an example of what I want to happen:

```
//this is the queries from the text area, this was taken from a dump MySQL file.


INSERT INTO `blank` VALUES ('11015', 'Mark', 'Caguia', 'C', '1/1/92', 'Philippines', '091083913121');
INSERT INTO `blank` VALUES ('11016', 'James', 'CaguiaYap', 'C', '1/1/92', 'Philippines', '091083913121');
INSERT INTO `blank` VALUES ('11017', 'Arwin', 'Santos', 'C', '1/1/92', 'Philippines', '091083913121');
INSERT INTO `blank` VALUES ('11018', 'Chris', 'Lutz', 'C', '1/1/92', 'Philippines', '091083913121');
INSERT INTO `blank` VALUES ('11019', 'Marcio', 'Laseter', 'C', '1/1/92', 'Philippines', '091083913121');
INSERT INTO `blank` VALUES ('11021', 'C.J.', 'Miles', 'C.', '1/26/2015 12:00:00 AM', 'USA', '0986531251');

// I have a couple of insert queries.
```

Now here's my code on executing the query.

```
 private void btnQueryManipulateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   

       {

//txtQueryStr is the name of my textarea.

strQuery = txtQueryStr.getText();
    try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/billing","root","");
        st = con.createStatement();
        String query = strQuery;
        pst =con.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.execute();
        tblCustomQuery.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

        }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex,"SQL Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

It can insert only one data but when I tried the above queries it returns an error which says I have an error on my sql syntax, and the error points on the second insert query line.

I don't know how to resolve this issue, I have search everything through internet but I got nothing. I would be very thankful if someone could help.
By the way my table name is blank and it has fields:

```
Customer_ID, fname,lname,mname,birthdate,address,mobile.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run multiple queries you need to invoke the JDBC execute operation multiple times. You can't prepare more than one query with a single `PreparedStatement`. Do it as follows:

```
// Split the queries into multiple strings
Sting[] queries = txtQueryStr.getText().split(";");

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                       "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/billing","root","");
    st = con.createStatement();

    // execute each query in a loop
    for (String query : queries) {
        st.executeUpdate(query.trim());
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex,"SQL Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
finally
{
    try {
        if (st != null) st.close();
        if (con != null) con.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {}
}
```

---

Actually, the code above isn't batching in the true sense. It's just executing multiple *statements* in a loop i.e. it's making *inserts* one by one but consecutively. To actually prepare & execute a batch, so that you hit the database only once, use `addBatch()` and `executeBatch()`.

```
for (String query : queries) {
    st.addBatch(query.trim());
}
int[] updateCounts = st.executeBatch();
```

The `int[]` array returned will contain the number of rows affected by each batch statement.

To save the time when each row is inserted into the database, take a look at my post [How to obtain a timestamp in Java and store in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28525992/1237040). I've outlined both the approaches there: generating the *timestamp* at the database side, or passing it from Java.